# How to use and pass routeprops in react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting error as below when i am using route.

```
Type: {history: History<PoorMansunknown>; location: Location<PoorMansUnknown>; match:match<any>; staticContext?:staticContext | undefined; onHide() => void} is not assignable to intrinsicattributes and props.
```

Property `onHide` does not exist on type Intrinsicattributes and props.

Below is the code snippet,

```
export const PopupContextProvider = ({ children }: any) => { {
    return (
        <PopupContext.Provider value={something}>
            <Route
                 path="/items/:itemId"
                 render={routeProps =>
                     condition1 || condition2 ? (
                         <React.Fragment>
                              <Child1 onHide={dismiss} {...routeProps} /> //getting e  error here
                         </React.Fragment>
                    ) : null
                } 
            />
        />
    );
}


type Props = RouteComponentProps<{ onHide: any }>;

export function Child1({ match }: Props) {
    const { onHide } = match.params;
    return(
        <div onClick={onHide}/>
    );
}
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Props = RouteComponentProps<{ onHide: any }>;
```

The RouteComponentProps generic is used to specify parameters that will come from matching the url. You apparently want onHide to be a normal prop, so this isn't the right code to use.

Use this instead:

```
interface Props extends RouteComponentProps {
  onHide: () => void;
}
```

Then you'll get access to onHide like this:

```
export function Child1({ match, onHide }: Props) {
    return(
        <div onClick={onHide}/>
    );
}
```